While creating the react app it is showing some errors
Error Image
Please see and help me.
I want to create react app. but it's not working.
the errors says that,
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\shubham\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\shubham\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\shubham\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-05-04T03_33_38_435Z-debug-0.log
Please give me some hints and help me.

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

It looks like your NPM directory is missing. This can be solved simply by installing a global package.
Open a command prompt as administrator to ensure your system doesn't block NPM creating the required files, and run npm install npm -g.
Generally running command prompt as administrator before running the create-react-app command may also help.
See NPM troubleshooting for more info
